# Add another marker on the map with current location and marker is visiable to bounds

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I am currently working on the map where i have to show two marker on the map , one is current position and another one is destination position and also they are at maximum zoom , both marker should be visiable with the map.
  Currently , I am getting the current location with the maximum zoom ,working perfectly , Now i am not getting how to add second marker i.e is destination and where to get maximium zoom.

Any Help Appreciated !! I tried :

```
public class MapMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    LatLng latLng;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mFragment;
    Marker currLocationMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_map_main);
        mFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googlemap);
        mFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap) {
        mGoogleMap = gMap;


        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        buildGoogleApiClient();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            //place marker at current position
            //mGoogleMap.clear();

            latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            currLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000); //3 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F); //1/10 meter
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //place marker at current position
        //mGoogleMap.clear();
        if (currLocationMarker != null) {
            currLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("My Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        currLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        Toast.makeText(this,"Location Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLng).zoom(14).build();

        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the destination latlng you want to show on Map?

Comment: @nitishpatel that i want to know , where to add destination lat and lng , i am hardording it  suppose destination lat and lng is 22.5726 and 88.3639

Comment: you can call it onMapReady() method by passing 22.5726 & 88.3639 as you show your current position.

Comment: thanks , let me give one try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `LatLngBounds` that includes both markers and then move the camera to that `LatLngBounds`:

```
// Add the markers to the map
LatLng latlng1 = new LatLng(8,48);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng1));
LatLng latlng2 = new LatLng(8.1,48.1);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng2));

// Make both markers visible
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(latlng1, latlng2); // Create a LatLngBounds including both LatLng
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50)); // Animate the camera to the given LatLngBounds with 50px padding
```